# Let $X$ normed vector space and $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ linear functional. Then $X = \ker f \oplus \langle x_0\rangle$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ a normed vector space and $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ linear functional. Then $X = \ker f \oplus \langle x_0\rangle $, where $x_0 \notin \ker f,$ any vector and $\langle x_0\rangle $ denotes the generated space.

It is obviously Hahn-Banach theorem, since it concerns about extensions. I tried unsuccessfully the following:

Take $x_0 \in \ker f^c$. Then $f(x_0) \neq 0$. We can make $f(x_0) > 0$ and $d(x_0,\ker f) = 1.$ So if we define $g : \ker f + \langle x_0\rangle \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$g(x + tx_0) := tf(x_0)$$
and note that
$$\|x + tx_0\| \ge |t|d(x_0,\ker f) = |t| = \frac{g(x+tx_0)}{f(x_0)}.$$ Then $g$ is bounded. So by the Hahn-Banach theorem there exists a extension $\tilde g$ of $f$ to $E.$ I can't proceed from here showing that $E = \ker f + \tilde x_0\rangle $ and $\tilde g = f$.

I do appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with functional analysis or Hahn-Banach, just linear algebra. Given $x \in X$, set 
$$x_1 = x - \frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}x_0, x_2 = \frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}x_0. $$

Then $x = x_1 + x_2$, $x_2 \in \left< x_0 \right>$ and

$$ f(x_1) = f(x) - \frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}f(x_0) = f(x) - f(x) = 0 $$

so $x_1 \in \ker(f)$. Finally, $\ker(f) \cap \left< x_0 \right> = \{ 0 \}$ because if $cx_0 \in \ker(f)$ then $f(cx_0) = cf(x_0) = 0$ which shows that $c = 0$.

Comment: just to clarify! I didn`t expect it would have such simple solution since this problem was proposed by a functional analysis book on the Hahn-Bannach section. I am sorry for my ingenuity.

Answer (score 1):

If $f\equiv 0$ there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, let $x_0\in X$ be such that $f(x_0)\neq 0$. Then for every $x\in X$, the vector $x-x_0f(x)/f(x_0)$ is in the kernel of $f$, so $x\in \hbox{Ker}f+\hbox{span}x_0$.